# Oracle Index columns

Tags: sql, oracle

This is a shortened example.  I realize I can't create indexes for every possible scenario but if I want to get our Data Warehouse down to 3-4 indexes per table, here is an example question.

If I have a table with Product, State, ZipCode, DatePurchased, and 50 other columns.
* and if a user sometimes wants to query by Product, 
* and then sometimes by Product & State
* and then sometimes by DatePurchased
* and then sometimes by State only

Do I need to make an index for these 4 scenarios? or can I do one index and include all 4 of these columns and Oracle will see i am only asking for one or two of the fields in my where clause?

Especially the Product & State, do i make one index and include both of these columns? and if the where clause only has Product will it hit that index? Or if I only want state, will it hit that index?  Or do I need a separate index, one for Product, one for state and one for Product & State combined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably create indexes on the following columns:

- (Product, State) <--- should be used by both Product and Product+State
  queries
- (State)
- (DatePurchased)

With regards to the last one; if the table is big or going to be big, I'd partition on the DatePurchased column, and that way, you get the benefit of partition pruning when you query on DatePurchased, and you probably wouldn't need a separate index.

As with everything, you should test it out with your tables and data!

Answer (score 1):

I try to keep it simple and adjust as necessary.  Since you know the user will be querying by product, state, and datepurchased, put an index on each of those 3 columns. It should help the product/state case as well. If empirically you discover the product/state case needs improvement, add it. BTW, extra indices will slow down inserts, but should not impact queries negatively.

Answer (score 0):

Create indexes on the following columns:

Product

DatePurchased

and partition on State.

Research some EXPLAIN PLANs on user queries (or your own test SQL) to see if the indexes are being used properly.

Also, experiment with Bitmap versus B-Tree indexes as these are common and useful in a Data Warehouse environment.

HTH